# Max of two years in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a string like this:

"I started in 1998 and finished around 2012"

I want to extract the "year" part from the string (the string in between the years can be anything and in any length), and then take the most recent year (so max of the years), I was trying to maybe identify the year with this:

```
SUBSTRING(YourValue, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue), 0), 4)
```

but I'm not sure how to get multiple years and then compare them.

Further, the most recent year doesn't have to be at the end of the string:

"I was done in 2013 but started in 1997."

I'm using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.7507)

Comment: You write "year" but that requires context. Do you ignore any other similar values in your string? Or just assume any 4 digit value that stands alone is a "year"? You will find punctuation (and mis-spellings) might be an issue, but you could try splitting for "words" using a space as separator. Unfortunately (as you already know) your goal is not well-suited to a SQL solution.

Comment: @SMor Yah im just gonna assume every 4 digit value is a year, with that assumption, would there be a way to compare multiple 4 digit values and get the max?

Comment: Do you always have a maximum of two numbers?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE @sometext VARCHAR(max) = 'I started in 1998 and finished around 2012';

select @sometext;

select TOP 1 * from string_split(@sometext,' ') where value between '1000' and '9999' order by value desc;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9d46267dc239cc00b4addb74334479e)

or, maybe:

```sql
select TOP 1 *  
from string_split(replace(replace(@sometext,'.',' '),',',' '),' ')
where value between '1000' and '9999' 
order by value desc;
```

when your sentence ends with a '.'.

Comment: And perhaps use try_convert in the where clause to find actual "numbers" if that goal is to actually use them as numeric values.

Comment: Yes [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would be a good addition. (It would actually make it a better answer.... )

Comment: `TRANSLATE` in newer versions might be better than `REPLACE` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1964adf597ff6b0ad66a1084ecc39dd

Comment: OP's ancient 2012 (v11.0.7507) version has no `string_split()`

Comment: The question says it is for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you all, I like this solution of splitting the string!

Answer (score -1):

It is not pretty, but as you can not tell how may dates there are, this is bound to be.

The CTE searches for dates, else returns NULL, that is in case no or only 1 date is there.

the following select check the lowest date as it must be the start date and also captures if one or both values of the CTE was NULL

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, YourValue varchar(299))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUEs(1,'I started in 1998 and finished around 2012'),(2,'I was done in 2013 but started in 1997.')
> ,(2,'I started in 2022.')
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS 
> (SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue) > 0 THEN
> SUBSTRING(YourValue, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue), 0), 4) ELSE NULL END
> val1 ,
> CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', RIGHT(YourValue, LEn(YourValue) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue) - 4)) > 0 
> THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT(YourValue, LEn(YourValue) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue) - 4) ,
> PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', RIGHT(YourValue, LEn(YourValue) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue) - 4)),4) 
> ELSE NULL END as val2
> FROM t1)
> SELECT CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL THEn val1 
> ELSE
> CASE WHeN val1 <= Val2 THEN val1 ELSE val2 END END as [STartdate]
> ,CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL THEn NULL
> ELSE CASe WHEN val1 > Val2 THEN val1 ELSE val2 END END as [ENDdate] FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> STartdate | ENDdate
> :-------- | :------
> 1998      | 2012   
> 1997      | 2013   
> 2022      | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03cdd8613dd20ae73adc09af1710b9b2)*

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is converting input *tokens* column into XML. It is done
  for tokenization of each word in a sentence.
- XQuery `.query()` method is using FLWOR expression to traverse all
  tokens, along the way it is checking for a YEAR data type (**xs:gYear** in XML parlance), and
  picking up a **max** year.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens varchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('I started in 1998 and finished around 2012'),
('I was done in 2013 but started in 1997.'),
('I started in 2022.');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1)
    , @dot CHAR(1) = '.';

SELECT t.*
   , c.query('
      for $x in max(/root/r[xs:gYear(./text()[1]) instance of xs:gYear]/text())
      return $x
   ').value('.','CHAR(4)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,@dot, ''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| id |                   tokens                   | Result |
+----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | I started in 1998 and finished around 2012 |   2012 |
|  2 | I was done in 2013 but started in 1997.    |   2013 |
|  3 | I started in 2022.                         |   2022 |
+----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
```